# Infinite Scrolling Texture

Tags: android, libgdx

I am using the libgdx framework and trying to repeat a background of spikes forever. The issue I am having is that the texture is moving extremely fast forever, but I want to slow it down. I was looking at [a tutorial from Google Code](https://code.google.com/p/libgdx-users/wiki/ScrollingTexture) and another user had this same issue. The "supposed" solution was this:

```
if(scrollTimer>1.0f)

    scrollTimer = 0.0f; 

scrollTimer = 3f;
```

This was to make it scroll *3 times faster*, so I attempted this and substituted 0.3f instead of 3f, but this makes the background at a standstill.

Here is some relevant code that might help in solving this issue:

```
public class PlayScreen implements Screen{

    final Rectangle upSpikeBounds = new Rectangle(0,0,Gdx.graphics.getWidth() * 2, 25);
    final Rectangle downSpikeBounds = new Rectangle(0,Gdx.graphics.getHeight() - 25,Gdx.graphics.getWidth() * 2, 25);
    Rectangle blockBounds;
    float total_time = 0f;
    Sprite spikeUpSprite, spikeDownSprite, spriteBlock;
    public PlayScreen(Game game){
        batch = new SpriteBatch();
        player = new Player(new Vector2(Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/10, Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/2), batch);
        stage = new Stage();
        this.game = game;

        Texture spikeUp = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("spikes.png"));
        Texture spikeDown = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("spikes.png"));
        spikeUp.setWrap(TextureWrap.Repeat, TextureWrap.Repeat);
        spikeDown.setWrap(TextureWrap.Repeat, TextureWrap.Repeat);
        spikeUpSprite = new Sprite(spikeUp, 0, 0, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), 25);
        spikeDownSprite = new Sprite(spikeDown, 0, 25, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), -25);
        spikeDownSprite.setPosition(0, Gdx.graphics.getHeight() - 20);
        spikeUpSprite.setSize(1200, 25);
        spikeDownSprite.setSize(1200, 25);

    }
    public void render(float deltaTime) {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        label.setText("Score: " + player.score);

        cam.position.set(player.getPosition().x + Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/2,Gdx.graphics.getHeight () / 2,0);
        batch.setProjectionMatrix(cam.combined);
        cam.update();

        total_time += Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
        if (total_time > 1.0f){
            total_time = 0.0f;
        }
        spikeUpSprite.setU(total_time);
        spikeUpSprite.setU2((total_time+1));
        spikeDownSprite.setU(total_time);
        spikeDownSprite.setU2(total_time+1);

        stage.act();
        batch.begin();
        spikeUpSprite.draw(batch);
        spikeDownSprite.draw(batch);
        batch.end();
        stage.draw();
    }

}
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

You should look up the tween engine, it will enable you to use 'tween animation', which is an animation of values, who  with a duration. For instance if you animate from zero to 700 with a 700ms duration, the value will start from zero and increase by 1 every ms

Answer (score 0):

While micnubinub's answer is certainly interesting and worth checking out, I have figured out a quick fix for my issue. The problem lies in this line:

```
total_time += Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
```

This is where the speed of the background lies. Because delta time is so fast (probably to the microsecond), the background scrolls by too fast. If I change it to a manual number, such as `0.0093f`, I get a background that scrolls at the speed I desire.